# Wordpress. LiteSpeed Cache. Как убрать автоинстал?

Tags: wordpress, litespeed

В последних версиях этот назойливый плагин ставится автоматом. При его удалении, через время, он устанавливается сам автоматически. Как его удалить навсегда?

Comment: Сменить хостера который это делает. Или нанять специалиста, который найдёт почему это происходит. ВП сам ничего не устанавливает.

Comment: @SeVlad а вот про хост это больше похоже. У них он часто мелькал, но раньше такого не было. Спасибо, гляну

Comment: Что за хостер?  ...

Answer (score 1):

Вы прибывали зайти в директорию установки плагина `\wp-content\plugins\` и удалить её от туда?

*вообще за такое WP организация наказывает, и [стоит пожаловаться](https://wordpress.org/plugins/) на данный плагин, если это действительно так, и у вас официальная сборка, а не хакнутая версия плагина.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде стало понятно, что с хостом проблему надо решать. Да, все официально конечно.